# unexpected token import nodejs, typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am using typescript, gruntjs, typeorm, typeorm-model-generator in my project for developing a Web API, when I try to start my app
I receive an `unexpected token import` error, but that is because is reading where I got my typescript files when it has to read the dist directory which is where all my js files are, and this error only happens if I add the code required to establish the connection to my database.

`app.ts`

```
export class Server {

 public app: express.Application; 

 public static bootstrap(): Server {
     return new Server();
 }

 constructor() {
    this.app = express();

    this.config();
    this.api();
 }

  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

    this.app.use(logger('dev'));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    this.app.use(function (error: any,
        request: express.Request, response: express.Response,
        next: express.NextFunction) {
            console.log(error);
            error.status = 404;
            response.json(error);
        });
  }

  private api(): void {
   // code that causes error
   // the output I recieve says
   // ./src/entity/myEntity.ts:1 unexpected token import
   // but if I remove it everything works fine
   typeorm.createConnection().then(async connection => {
        console.log("Conexion establecida");
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
  }

}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I kill myself already.

Comment: **Should I kill myself already.** - no don't

Comment: How are running the code? It is probably pointing at the wrong directory. FYI: `"lib": ["es5", "es6"]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I run it with  `npm run dev`, which points to `./bin/www.js` which is the file that starts the app, there I have a require statement for `dist/app.js`, so It should work fine. I am sorry my mistake it was `lib: ["es6"]`

Comment: When I do that, I don't receive any output.

Comment: Well, that is because you apps entry point does not produce any. Not sure what you expect but I would argue strongly that wrapping your logic in a class is entirely unhelpful.

Comment: Really? Why? Should I change it?

Comment: Well you can, but you need to do something more fundamental first and regardless. Figure out how you expect your code behave. Given what you have I would expect `node dist/app.js` to emit no output and so would say that it is behaving correctly

Comment: Well I'll check it in more detail, but given that www.js points to dist/app.js should the output would lead me to the location, I am only calling app.js

Comment: Well, I think I do use it, if you see the `bootstrap` method I return an instance of the class, then in `www.js` through that instance I gain access to the public `app` property which I use to start the app.

Comment: Well you did not say that before. So if you run `node bin/www.js` does it work?

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry for that, I am so worried for this thing not working. Nope I received the error of unexpected token import, it says that the error is in src/entity/aviso.ts but it should not be reading that file e.e

Comment: search for it, maybe you have a incorrect import somewhere.

Comment: Maybe I did a mistake with the ormconfig.json e.e, I will check it out, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue. The problem is likely in your `ormconfig.json`. The generated `ormconfig.json` points to the entities in your src folder as the ones to call, instead of the entity js files in your dist or build folder. Checkout the question I also asked: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token import typeORM entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361948/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import-typeorm-entity)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out later, thank you very much for your response anyway :).

Comment: Haha yea, I saw it was 3 months old, but figured I should just post my answer anyways.