# typescript tsc Unexpected token { on import

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I know this is a common problem and it seems like `"module": "commonjs"` in ts config must help, but it does not.

node `v11.4.0`,
tsc `3.4.3`

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es2017",
         "dom"
      ],
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "rootDir": "src"
   },
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

import in `.ts` file:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn} from "typeorm";
```

**build & run:**

1. `tsc`
2. `node build/server.js`

**error** :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn} from "typeorm";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

please help :)

**Update:**
It appears only in single `.ts` file. imports in other files work fine. At the same time it is the only file which uses imports from `typeorm` module.

Comment: Can you try change target from `es6` to `es2015`. `es2015` works well to me.

Comment: yeah i did tried it. 
it's a really weird prob, appears only for one file (there are multiple imports in other files which works well)

Comment: I found the solution to this error [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375317/1354873).

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like "module": "commonjs" in ts config must help, but it does not.

It should. Its not working as the tsconfig isn't being used. You should be running `tsc` and providing the project file:

```
tsc -p .
```

Comment: tried, didn't help. why do you think it is not being used? If i set `baseUrl` for example, it certainly works.

Comment: @user The output is clearly not CommonJS. OTOH, why not run it with `node --experimental-modules`?

Answer (score 0):

First check the tsconfig, must be these configurations:

```
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

After, check if you are starting the JAVASCRIPT file and not the TYPESCRIPT file

```
//Wrong:
node ....../file.ts

//Correct:
node ....../file.js
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a path problem. cd dir build, node server.js

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, was experiencing this issue with TypeORM library, this resolved the runtime error of the output build I was getting.