# Cannot generate the migration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have one project using typeorm to create the database. And when I execute the command to generate a migration to my project, it gives me the error

I have the following orm configuration json file:

```
 {
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "",
   "database": "postgres",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "src/entity/**/*.ts"
  ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
         "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
        }
    }
```

I have this User entity class:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Transaction } from "./Transactions";
export type UserStatus = "Active" | "Inactive";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column("varchar",{
    length:50
})
account_id: string;

@Column("varchar",{
    length: 50
})
name: string;

@Column("varchar",{
    length:50
})
email: string;

@Column("varchar",{
    length:15
})
phone_number: string;

@Column("varchar",{
    length:50
})
address: string;

@Column({
    type: "enum",
    enum: ["Active", "Inactive"]
}) status: UserStatus;


@Column("varchar",{
    length:50
})
current_id: string;

@OneToMany(type => Transaction, transaction => transaction.user)
transactions: Transaction[];

}
```

If I execute the command to generate a migration, it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\Firdaus97\source\repos\Cust Local payment\Cust Local payment\MyProject>ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migrations:generate -n
C:\Users\Firdaus97\source\repos\Cust Local payment\Cust Local payment\MyProject\node_modules\.bin\typeorm:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Firdaus97\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:158:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue on **Windows 10**, and was able to fix it as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800088/813103) and [this comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/371#issuecomment-368902327):

In my `package.json` scripts I earlier had

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
  }
```

I replaced
"typeorm" with

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm:win": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules\\typeorm\\cli.js",
    "migration:generate:win": "npm run typeorm:win migration:generate -- -n"
  }
```

And then this worked like a charm `npm run migration:generate:win -n <<migration name>>`

Answer (score 8):

Remove `ts-node` from your command and try again:

```sh
.\node_modules\.bin\typeorm migrations:generate -n
```

`typeorm` in your node_modules already an executable, you don't have to use `ts-node`, which is only means for TypeScript files.

#### Other solutions:

1. npm script:

Create a script in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "migrate": "typeorm migrations:generate -n"
  }
}
```

Run it with npm:

```sh
npm run migrate
```

2. Use `npx`

Since version `5.2` of npm, you can do this:

```sh
npx typeorm migrations:generate -n
```

3. Use `yarn`

```sh
yarn typeorm migrations:generate -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rachit Kyte.One It work with me:

I replaced `typeorm` with

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm:win": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules\\typeorm\\cli.js",
    "migration:generate:win": "npm run typeorm:win migration:generate -- -n"
  }
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35704692)